# How to work with Dev C++

Tags: dev-c++

I am new in programming. but i know turbo C & i can work with it. But how to work on Dev C++?
i means 1.How to Compile & 2. How to Run. I have Windows so if anyone help me with proper example than it will be great.

Comment: Please edit the tags in your question to replace `c++builder` with `dev-c++` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Dev c++ is very simple! To do the basic, Open you file, compile and run using the menu Execute!

However, if u are starting something new now, I would suggest you consider using eclipse. It is not so easy in the first days but the long term gain is giant!

I would like to improve my answer... I suggested that you should consider using eclipse. I still think that eclipse is great. Furthermore, I had had some problems with the old version of dev c++. After reading the comment of @Orwell (which provided facts that I didn't know), I checked the new version and the issues that I had had before disappeared. So, the big picture of dev c++ is that it is a program that works well and it is very simple. There is a cost to start using eclipse!

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibonacci(int n){
    if(n==1)return 0;
    if(n==2)return 1;
    if(n>=3)return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2);
}

int main(){

   // 

   int n =10;
   cout << "The element of the Fibonacci series is " << fibonacci(n) << "\n";   


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If u give me an example of C in Dev C++, than it will be great. Because i don't know what will be a header file in Dev C++. Is there are any different between Dev C++ & Turbo C?

Comment: ok... You have a very simple example above... I am not sure if I have used Turbo C before. I have been using Dev C++ for a long time and before that I don't remember. Have fun!